# Is there a way to combine tabs and side menu in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

Is there any way that the menu button is inside one of the tabs as shown in the image,
I have searched in several forums and I only find that the button dle mene places it at the top in the header, but none that the menu button is one of the options of the tabs[image]

Comment: Check this Demo repository: https://github.com/Saqib92/ionic5-tabs-sidemenu

Answer (score 2):

First create your ionic application with tabs
In app.component.html just add this code

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content" when="false">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-list-header>Inbox</ion-list-header>
          <ion-note>hi@ionicframework.com</ion-note>
          <ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false" *ngFor="let p of pages">
            <ion-item [routerLink]="[p.url]" routerLinkActive="selected" routerDirection="root" lines="none" detail="false">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

add pages array in app.component.ts and customize your pages

```
pages = [
    {
      title: 'Login',
      url: '/tabs/tab1',
      icon: 'log-in'
    },
    {
      title: 'Contact',
      url: '/tabs/tab2',
      icon: 'person'
    },
    {
      title: 'About',
      url: '/tabs/tab3',
      icon: 'information-circle'
    }
  ];
```

In tabs-routing.module.ts just add a new route "tab4" and do not give any children or loadchildren property like this. If you do not give tab 4 in route then it will show error

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },

      {
        path: 'tab4',
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

then in your tabs.page.html add this code

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="triangle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab 1</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="ellipse"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab 2</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="square"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab 3</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>


    <ion-tab-button tab="tab4">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment or remove `<ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>` from your pages header

If you do not understand anything let me knnow and I will create and share a github repo with you with proper project structure

Answer (score 0):

Create your project with tabs. `ionic start projectName tabs`

Update your `app.component.html` with below Code:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content" when="false">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-list-header>Inbox</ion-list-header>
          <ion-note>hi@ionicframework.com</ion-note>
          <ion-menu-toggle autoHide="false" *ngFor="let p of pages">
            <ion-item [routerLink]="[p.url]" routerLinkActive="selected" routerDirection="root" lines="none" detail="false">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [ios]="p.icon + '-outline'" [md]="p.icon + '-sharp'"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

update your `app.component.ts`

```
pages = [
    {
      title: 'Login',
      url: '/tabs/tab1',
      icon: 'log-in'
    },
    {
      title: 'Contact',
      url: '/tabs/tab2',
      icon: 'person'
    },
    {
      title: 'About',
      url: '/tabs/tab3',
      icon: 'information-circle'
    }
  ];
```

For Complete demo repository based on Ionic 5:
https://github.com/Saqib92/ionic5-tabs-sidemenu